Odoo Database Access Issue Following Installation of Muk Module
Recently, we decided to install Muk Backend Theme in Odoo Community V.17.
Module: https://apps.odoo.com/apps/themes/17.0/muk_web_theme/
However, after finishing the installation of this module, everything seemed to go well, so we tried to change the default color of the configuration.
From that moment until now, we are not longer able to access the database, resulting in an error message:
Error while render the template ValueError: File(s) /muk_web_colors/static/src/scss/colors_light.scss not found in bundle web._assets_primary_variables Template: website.layout Path: /t/html/head/t[11] Node:  El error ocurrió al renderizar la plantilla. website.layout y evalúe la siguiente expresión: 
We tried to solve it by deleting and adding again the files of the module, but we don't longer have idea of how to solve it, now the only error message is "500: Internal Server Error".
We greatly appreciate your prompt attention to this critical matter.
I am available for any further queries you may have.

I did, I installed version 17

If you have access to the database you can try to mark the module(s) as to remove:
UPDATE ir_module_module SET state='to remove' WHERE name='my_module';

After that restart Odoo. It should remove the module on first load.
If you still get an error, a update of all modules afterwards could help.
odoo -c /path/to/the/config/file -d my_database -u all --stop-after-init --max-cron-threads=0 --no-http

I did it, it didn't solve the problem

Just remove the installed module folder and restart odoo service.

could you provide the commands to restart in your answer?
